# What Django packages for community group management website similar to meetup.com

Tags: python, django

I need to quickly develop a free (for users), open source, standalone system for multiple group event management. It will be similar to a scaled down version of meetup.com. Django looks like it would potentially be a good framework to use. I have used Python in the past but have little experience with Django specifically.

On top of the standard user management functionality this system would need to be able allow users to

- create social groups e.g. A choir group or A dinner club
- create events within a group
- users can join groups
- group users can then join events

Can any more experienced Django developers please point me at any existing packages that can do some of this already and save me from re-building the wheel? Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have a look at http://pinaxproject.com

Comment: Thank you for responding init3. Pinax was one of the first things I looked at. I was very put off by how little information they provide on their website regarding what features their start-up projects include. Is there a particular start-up project of theirs that you can recommend I start with?

Comment: there was some good documentation on the very beginning - but thats about 2-3 years ago. Sorry :-/

Comment: btw. you had a look at https://www.djangopackages.com ?

Comment: Indeed I did. The package search results helpfully state the name and if a package is still under active development (which is really good) but doesn't provide even the briefest summary of what any particular package does unless you click through to the package page. I was and still am too lazy to manually click through over 2,000 package pages and was hoping a more experienced Django user could point me at some particular packages that would be suitable.

Comment: Well, I'm developing with python/django over 6 years now...but honestly - because I'm to lazy to check all packages, too, I'm mostly developing all my stuff I need from scratch and now got a "own package-box" except: django-tagging i <3 it :)

Comment: Thanks for your helpful feedback init3. I guess I'll have to go the diy route (or re-consider frameworks in less enjoyable languages)